# Beamer: non-coloring effect onslide

Tags: beamer

I want to achieve an effect similar to `alert` but instead of a color I want to put a circle around something.

The command for the circle:

```
\newcommand<>\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
    \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}%
}
```

Ideal use: `circled<4>{text}`

Current work around: `\only<4>{\circled{text}}\onslide<1-3>{text}`

I know I could wrap the current work around in a new command but I will lose the functionality of <>. Any better ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then `aobs` package to the rescue!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\newcommand<>\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
    \node[shape=circle,inner sep=2pt,alt=#2{draw}{}] (char) {#1};}%
}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \circled<4>{3}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```